# How do i set a callback for end of song/file with bass?

Tags: c#, .net, bass

I am using [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html). I would like to set a callback so when the song reaches to end i can play another song directly after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not C#, but here's some VB.Net code you should be able to convert easily enough:

Set up the callback

```
' Mixer handle to the bass synch callback when the current track in the mixer ends
Private m_MixerSynchProc As Un4seen.Bass.SYNCPROC
Private m_MixerSyncHandle As Int32 = 0

' Create a new callback for when the current track in the mixer has ended
m_MixerSynchProc = New Un4seen.Bass.SYNCPROC(AddressOf CurrentTrackEnded)

m_MixerSyncHandle = Bass.BASS_ChannelSetSync(m_MixerHandle, Un4seen.Bass.BASSSync.BASS_SYNC_END Or Un4seen.Bass.BASSSync.BASS_SYNC_MIXTIME, 0, m_MixerSynchProc, 0)
```

A delegate sub that BASS will call when the track is ended

```
' Mixer sync proc callback for when the current track has ended
Private Sub CurrentTrackEnded(ByVal MixerHandle As Int32, ByVal Channel As Int32, ByVal Data As Int32, ByVal User As IntPtr)
    ' Do stuff here when the track ends
End Sub
```